# Google Sheets - Using ArrayFormula with Conditional and Embedded Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This may be far more simple than I think. What I'm trying to do is use the ArrayFormula to copy an existing formula to all the rows in a particular column.

To begin with, I have several columns along the lines of:

[image]

What I'm doing is adding the first three numbers and multiplying them by the fourth. I also have an IF condition in which, if the fourth column is blank, I leave the value in column 5 blank.

Now, I'm trying to convert this to an ArrayFormula to repeat this for all the rows in column 5.

So I went from:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E2)=TRUE,,SUM((B2+C2+D2)*E2))
```

to this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(E2:E)=TRUE,,SUM((B2+C2+D2)*E2)))
```

But what this does is, when I add a new row, ALL of the values in column 5 are set to the same value. Here is an example:

[image]

So, my first thought was to set the range on the SUM formula and change it to:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(E2:E)=TRUE,,SUM((B2:B+C2:C+D2:C)*E2:E)))
```

But that just makes all the values to sum of all of what the individual values should be...so, in my example, it works out to 435 (60 + 135 + 240).

What am I doing wrong here? The values in column 5 should be different in each row (e.g., row 2 should be 135 and row 3 should be 240).

Thanks!

Comment: if google why the excel tag?

Comment: ^^^^ Fixed it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(E2:E)=TRUE,, (B2:B+C2:C+D2:D)*E2:E))
```

`SUM` is not supported under `AF`

Comment: My apologies for the mis-tag...it was just offered as a suggested tag and I figured it was about the same thing.

In any event, that resolved it! Thank you so much!

Comment: To complete this answer here is the reference to [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en).